# Is it true that the red lights on building antennas help the aircraft "detect/visualize" ground objects?

Tags: safety, ground-operations

I was thinking that red lights on the antennas on buildings help aircraft to see if there are tall objects in the ground. Is this right?
[image: normal hazard light]

Source

Comment: Try this. Synchronize your eyes to the blinking of the lights such that you never see them on. While maintaining your blink speed and duration, spin around in a circle (slower makes it easier for you). When you get back around, find the tower. At night, this is really, really, really hard. Imagine doing that in an airplane...

Comment: @corsika I don't understand the point of the blinking and spinning exercise.

Comment: No, the red lights are for the pilots to see.  Very few aircraft (maybe some drones?) are capable of seeing things.

Comment: @JonathanWalters You're trying to see what the towers look like without the lights on. It's a lot easier (and fun!) to just synchronize your eyes to their blink such that you never see the lights on than it is to actually turn the lights off. Also safer. You spin around so it's harder to cheat from when you saw the lights on. Bonus: once you play around with it, you can play games with the lights and have them shoot other lights!! Takes a while to learn how but once you do it's super fun.

Comment: @corsika Is the exercise supposed to contribute to situational awareness or collision avoidance, or is it supposed to be for amusement? Personally, I find towers and windmills to be deadly serious matters.

Comment: Seems fairly obvious to me that the purpose of the exercise is to demonstrate a concept without having to actually get in a plane.

Comment: @JonathanWalters It's to illustrate why those lights are so important - the things they illuminate are very difficult to find even if you know there's something to look for. The fact that you can use them for entertainment when a passenger on long roadtrips is just a bonus feature.

Comment: @corsika OK, in other words, an unlighted building or tower is hard to see...

Comment: At a smaller general aviation airport, you can take a demo flight. If you can take one at night, you'll see how it works. If it's clear you can see these from quite a distance.

Comment: It surprises me that nobody pointed this out yet, but beside the obvious safety reasons these lights can prove quite useful for navigation under certain conditions. "My" three towers around "my" airfield help me a great deal for the first rough line-up, especially in dim light.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Those lights are used to show obstacles that may interfere with the aircraft's course, such as antennas, buildings, wind turbines, and they are mandatory.
The name of those lights is Aircraft Warning Lights, and here is an [article from Wikipedia about them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_warning_lights).

Comment: I was in a city-wide power blackout once (rain flooding the electrical substations), and it was notable that (apart from a hospital and car headlights) the only signs of electricity were those aircraft warning lights on (all) the tall buildings ... i.e. fwiw they're important enough to have backup (battery or generator) power.

Comment: @ChrisW: In a lot of countries they are so important that they are run by dual backup batteries, sometimes plus generator and every light you visually see is run by at least two bulbs.

Comment: I've seen the control panel for one of these "lights" in a water tower, and it's amazing how complex it is for a simple light.  Multiple redundancies and backup power sources.

Comment: @JPhi1618 it makes sense, since their failure leads to very, very big problems.

Comment: Lights are increasingly useful for situational awareness when visibility worsens for any reason (night, fog, rain...)

Comment: But they're a pain to change ;-) Cold fingers and hot bulbs :-(

Comment: The lights are also useful for any constructions near helipads, such as hospitals. I'd imagine helicopters are more likely to fly near ground/buildings than GA aircrafts.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, the lighting is helpful for collision avoidance.

The red lights are helpful, but the white strobes can be even better for visibility.

When I am flying very low to the ground I am far more concerned about towers and windmills (or occasionally high tension power lines) than buildings. Fortunately all of my *really* low flying for work is done during daylight hours, but in heavy overcast or other low-light conditions the lights are very helpful.

Most tall buildings are in congested areas and most flight operations will be required to maintain an altitude of 1000 feet or more above such structures. The presence of towers in excess of 500 feet, and especially in excess of 1000 feet, in uncongested areas posses a much more credible threat to VFR low level flight.

The FAA describes the standards for structure and tower lighting in [AC70/7460-1L](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_70_7460-1L_.pdf). Generally, any structure that exceeds 200 ft AGL should be marked and/or lighted.

Note that, though the lighting may be mandatory, it may be [NOTAM](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_70_7460-1L_.pdf)ed out of service.
For example:

> `!SFF 02/009 SFF OBST TOWER LGT (ASR 1060807) 473535.00N1171750.00W (5.5NM S SFF) 3971.1FT (352.4FT AGL) OUT OF SERVICE`

Comment: Could you unpack or link “NOTAMed out of service” for the novices among the readers?

Comment: @sevensideddie Good idea, standby.

Comment: NOTAM stands for "[NOtice To AirMen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOTAM)", and is an official notice filed with the local, regional, or national aviation authority to alert pilots of hazards or other deviations from normal protocols along their flight path.

Answer (score 6):

Before the lights were installed, [this happened...](http://www.portsmouth.co.uk/heritage/plane-s-collision-showed-strength-of-local-mast-1-3675080)

[image]
[image]
(second picture via [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/417145984210630603/))

A better picture of this incident (a 1915 Sopwith Baby at Horsea Island in 1917) appears in the front of the 1925 edition of the "Admiralty Handbook of Wireless Telegraphy" in a slightly snarky advert, captioned "A proof of the quality of Elwell masts".

Comment: Also, in NYC [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-25_Empire_State_Building_crash) happened.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question directly, no, they are not used to indicate that you are too close to the ground.  Some of them are over 1500 feet high.

They are used so you do not fly into them for obvious reasons or fly too close to them for less obvious reasons:

1. Some are powerful transmitters and can interfere with the systems on the aircraft.
2. Towers often have support wires which extend a long way from the obstacle with the light and do not have lights themselves.

Too close to the ground is figured out by looking; by the altimeter; by charts and by planning.

The red light just means "keep away!"

[Some incidents and analysis of interference and even crashes attributed to high intensity EMR.](http://www.rvs.uni-bielefeld.de/publications/Incidents/DOCS/Research/Rvs/Article/EMI.html)

[Some follow up on the Blackhawk crashes.](http://catless.ncl.ac.uk/Risks/5.58.html#subj2)

Whilst [this paper](https://www.icheme.org/communities/subject_groups/safety%20and%20loss%20prevention/resources/hazards%20archive/~/media/Documents/Subject%20Groups/Safety_Loss_Prevention/Hazards%20Archive/XX/XX-Paper-62.pdf) focusses primarily on the ability of high powered EMR sources to cause ignition sparks up to 30kms away (!), it also shows how dangerous they are up to hundreds of metres away.

If anyone remains unconvinced that powerful transmitters need to be avoided by aircraft, please let me know and I'll do some more digging, but for now, I have an "all nighter" I need to pull to deliver a project tomorrow so I may be some time....

Comment: *"Some of them are over a kilometre high."*  
I have never heard of an obstacle over a kilometre tall.  The [world's tallest antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVLY-TV_mast) is only 600m tall.

Comment: `Some are powerful transmitters and can interfere with the systems on the aircraft.` Has this ever been documented to occur?

Comment: Personally, I have flown quite close to some of the transmitters (I don't know how powerful though) without any negative impact to aircraft systems. Such proximity would only be possible in VFR flight, where any possible system impact would be negligible for safety of flight.

Comment: A "drive by downvote" with no comment.  I couldn't care less that I've lost a whole 2 rep points, but it really grates me that I can learn nothing from it.

Comment: @abelenky  Sorry, a simple typo which I fixed at the same time you where typing your comment.

Comment: @TomMcW Yes. I'm searching for references, both to the occurrences and to the guidelines which specify separation distances.  I'll edit to include.

Comment: @JonathanWalters So because you have not experienced being struck by lightning, it doesn't happen?  We're not talking about PEDs here.  We're talking multi-megawatt transmitters which generate significant harmonics and EMR on multiple sidelobes powerful enough to be dangerous, in some cases up to hundreds of metres.  Many transmitters have "no human" zones when radiating.  What leads you to conclude that such proximity can only occur when VFR?  I don't get that at all.  For example, IFR flights into London were, until it was retired, routed away from the old Crystal Palace TV transmitter.

Comment: @Simon I'm only sharing my personal experience. The proximity I am referring to would not be possible in IFR flight. And I did not downvotes fwiw.

Comment: @Simon Glad to see you've recovered from your Corsair hysteria. Here's an upvote to counter that drive-by

Comment: @Simon:  I did not drive-by-downvote.  Your original post claimed obstacles over a kilometre, which is just unrealistic.  I commented, and down-voted for an answer not based in reality.  I would now remove my downvote, but it is currently locked. Don't pretend it was a drive-by when my comments are clear and timestamped.

Comment: @JonathanWalters Why?  Are you assuming that IFR traffic is only ever where it should be?  I also know you didn't downvote, I "virtually" know all the main players on here and it's not how we behave ;)

Comment: @abelenky I didn't think it was you which is why my comment was not addressed to anyone.  Don't worry about reversing it, I really don't care, but thanks for letting me know that was the reason.  You might consider adding "-1" so people know, otherwise, I have no way of knowing and therefore, it's a drive by.

Comment: I suppose I am making that assumption. To be clear I am talking about positions within 100 ft of the transmitter and at a level with, or below it.

Comment: @JonathanWalters Yep, that's the problem area, actually, for the big TV transmitters, the danger zone can extend beyond 100 metres. I am determined to find the relevant links.  (BTW, ex-avionics engineer and I know the problems caused by powerful EMR which need very special attention to be paid to shielding and antenna designs usually not found outside military and big iron -e.g. missing in some bizjets and most GA)

Comment: OK, yeah, I would be very interested in more info on the transmitters since I have to fly pretty close to a lot of them for work.